# Able to flag as 'Not an answer' after having reviewed 'Not an answer'

Tags: support, close-reasons, flagging

I just came across [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/11971/595) (corresponding [question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/stone-identification)) and I was able to flag it as *Not an answer* (2) after I already marked it *Not an answer* in a review queue (1).

[image]

Shouldn't that be impossible?

(Or is it because at this moment *It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.*?)

[Here is the question timeline](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/10848/timeline)

---

[Edit 3 Aug] The same things just happened with a question on Workplace.se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the system has worked for several years, so I suppose it's by design. The behavior is not hard to reproduce: just open [any post you already reviewed](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/595/jan-doggen?tab=activity&sort=reviews), and you'll be able to flag it any way you want, unless the post is already gone.

The following things can prevent you from raising a flag on a post are:

1. You already raised a flag *of the same kind* in the past.
2. You have a *pending* flag on that post (of whatever type)
3. The post is locked or deleted
4. You are out of flags for the day (or don't have enough reputation to cast flags).

Having reviewed a post in the past does not disqualify you from raising another flag on it. There's been some [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144858) whether flagging posts you see in review is reasonable. Generally it's a waste of time even though additional NAA/VLQ flags [do have a slight effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277293) on the likelihood of the post getting deleted.

The review system does not show users the posts they already flagged, although [there's an edge case with multiple browser tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204694).